# Twitter bootstrap responsive layout

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I made this responsive layout. It works fine until the width of the screen is less then 800px, it gets messed up.

How can I fix this so the logo's just 'shrink' and don't re-arrange themself underneath each other?

http://jsfiddle.net/hashie5/Pnc3g/

html:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="testimonials row-fluid">
    <div class="span6">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12"> <a href="#"><img src="http://www.flexmail.net/images/logos/logo_flexmail.png" alt="gas" /></a> <a href="#"><img src="http://www.flexmail.net/images/logos/logo_flexmail.png" alt="gas" /></a></div>
            <a href="#"><img src="http://www.flexmail.net/images/logos/logo_flexmail.png" alt="gas" /></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="http://www.flexmail.net/images/logos/logo_flexmail.png" alt="gas" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span3"> <a href="#"><img src="http://www.flexmail.net/images/logos/logo_flexmail.png" alt="gas" /></a></div>
            <div class="span3"> <a href="#"><img src="http://www.flexmail.net/images/logos/logo_flexmail.png" alt="gas" /></a></div>
            <div class="span3"> <a href="#"><img src="http://www.flexmail.net/images/logos/logo_flexmail.png" alt="gas" /></a></div>
            <div class="span3"> <a href="#"><img src="http://www.flexmail.net/images/logos/logo_flexmail.png" alt="gas" /></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span3"> <a href="#"><img src="http://www.flexmail.net/images/logos/logo_flexmail.png" alt="gas" /></a></div>
            <div class="span3"> <a href="#"><img src="http://www.flexmail.net/images/logos/logo_flexmail.png" alt="gas" /></a></div>
            <div class="span3"> <a href="#"><img src="http://www.flexmail.net/images/logos/logo_flexmail.png" alt="gas" /></a></div>
            <div class="span3"> <a href="#"><img src="http://www.flexmail.net/images/logos/logo_flexmail.png" alt="gas" /></a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span6">
        <div class="quote">
            <div class="text">
                <em>Congratulations! It is really a great tool, it is very friendly for us. Creating a new message is so easy with your smart builder. Thank you for that. 10/10</em>
            </div>
            <div class="author">JUAN ISAAC RODRIGUEZ, Credit Report, Peru.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.testimonials {
    background-color:#f7f7f7;
}
.quote {
    background: url("http://www.flexmail.net/images/quote_home.gif") left top no-repeat;
    height: 128px;
    margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
}
.quote .text {
    color: #444444;
    line-height: 22px;
}
.quote .author {
    color: #666666;
    float: left;
    font-family:'colaboratelightregular';
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 22px;
    margin: 10px 0 0;
}
```

Comment: don't you have a live example? a jsfiddle is not the best way to show an responsive design.

Comment: live example: http://www.flexmail.net/ , there is nothing else on this site but is it safe to just share a website url your still working on?

Comment: yes no problem. i do too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every `spanX` will become a row with the width of 100% in narrower windows. That's whats causing your mess :)

Maybe this is an alternative solution, but not the best since we have duplicate the images in the html-code.

I've added some **css**

```
.visible-phone img {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
}
```

And some **html**

```
<div class="row-fluid visible-phone">
    <a href="#"><img src="http://www.flexmail.net/images/logos/logo_flexmail.png" alt="gas" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://www.flexmail.net/images/logos/logo_flexmail.png" alt="gas" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://www.flexmail.net/images/logos/logo_flexmail.png" alt="gas" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://www.flexmail.net/images/logos/logo_flexmail.png" alt="gas" /></a>
</div>
```

All the images appear two times in the html. Notice the classes `visible-phone` and `hidden-phone` on the `div`s wrapping the images.

http://jsfiddle.net/Pnc3g/5/

Comment: any suggestions on how to fix this and still make it responsible?

Comment: How do you want the layout in narrower windows?

Comment: I guess 4x3 to a 2x6 grid and keep the logo's smaller (they get smaller now when you resize that's good), keep shrinking the right text and if the screen gets even smaller put the text underneath the logo's